# Spring MVC - Setting bean from form data

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc

I am creating a spring mvc application. I need to create a bean using the form data and that should be available via my application context in the rest of my application. Right now I have the following in my applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="si" class="com.sty.wor.ServiceInstance">
        <constructor-arg index="0"><ref bean="myURL"/></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="1"> <value>username</value> </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="2"><value>password</value> </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg index="3"><value>true</value> </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

<bean id="myURL" class="java.net.URL">
        <constructor-arg index="0"><value>https://10.10.60.10/app</value> </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

Please tell me how I can get the data for these bean creations from a form [I want to create these beans after the form data validation]. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Read about the concept of a "form-backing object" in the reference [documentation chapter on MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html).

Comment: Form backing objects are not application scoped instances.

Comment: No - nothing in Spring MVC will take a single http request and create an application-scoped bean out of it. If this is logic you desire you would have to create it yourself.

Comment: I am new to this - How would people normally create objects based on their login information (like from the login page)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your bean beforehand and update it with your form data. Beware of synchronization issues.

Comment: I can't modify the values because the object is from an API and won't expose setters to set that data.

Answer (score 0):

M99, if you declare the bean as a spring bean like that it will create only one object until you shutdown the web container(that is called application scope). Because spring beans are default singleton.

Normally developers do not create object like `com.sty.wor.ServiceInstance` in that way. After login, just create a new instance in java code "`new Employee(myUrl,userName,password,true)`" and save it in the session for later use.

For example `request.getSession().setAttribute("loggedinEmployee",employee)`